# Proofs of a character identity?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, characters, character-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $g \geq 0, k\geq 1 $ integers, and $(C_1,...,C_k)$ a tuple of conjugacy classes of $G$.  I am interested in proofs of the following identity

$$
\sum_{(c_1,...,c_k) \in C_1 \times \cdots \times C_k} \sum_{V_\lambda} d(V_\lambda)^{1-2g} \chi_\lambda(c_1^{-1}\cdots c_k^{-1}) = |C_1|\cdots|C_k|\sum_{V_\lambda} d(V_\lambda)^{2-2g-k}\chi_\lambda(c_1)\cdots \chi_\lambda(c_k)
$$

where the sums with $V_\lambda$ are over all irreducible characters of $G$ and $d(V_\lambda) = \chi_\lambda(1)$ is the dimension of the representation.  I obtained this from messing around with a theorem due to Frobenius (for $g=0$ and later generalized originally using a quantum topology approach - hence the $g$ for genus).

Is there some nice (ideally purely character-theoretic) proof of this identity?

Comment: This seems closely related to the functional identity $\lvert C_2\rvert\chi_\lambda(c_1)\chi_\lambda(c_2) = \chi_\lambda(1)\sum_{c_2' \in C_2} \chi_\lambda(c_1 c_2')$.  I don't see the proof immediately, but I'll think about it.  (Note that the inverses don't change anything, as re-indexing by $\lambda \mapsto \overline\lambda$ in the first sum shows.)

Comment: is not it true that for fixed $\lambda$ we have (the contribution of $\lambda$ to LHS)=(the contribution of $\bar{\lambda}$ to RHS)?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, yup, I'm writing the proof now.

Comment: What is the $d$ in $d(V_\lambda)^{1 - 2g}$ ?

Comment: @InesInstitoris It is the dimension of $V_\lambda$ - thanks I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand\card[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$I use the functional identity $\card{C_1}\chi(c_1)\chi(c_2) = \chi(1)\sum_{c_1' \in C_1} \chi(c_1' c_2)$, which identifies multiples of irreducible characters $\chi$, and which I'll re-write in the form
$$
\sum_{c_1 \in C_1} \chi(c_1)\chi(c_2)
= \chi(1)\sum_{c_1 \in C_1} \chi(c_1 c_2).
$$
This was my advisor (Paul Sally)'s all-time favourite result, and I am delighted to have a chance to use it.

I replace the cardinality on the RHS by a sum over $C_1 \times \dotsb \times C_k$.  I also re-index the LHS by $\overline\lambda$ instead of $\lambda$, so that there's no need for inverses.  Finally, I work with the $\chi$-by-$\chi$ version, as suggested by @FedorPetrov in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388863/proofs-of-a-character-identity#comment990319_388863), in the sense that
$$
\chi(1)^{1 - 2g}\sum_{(c_1, \dotsc, c_k) \in C_1 \times \dotsb \times C_k} \chi(c_1\dotsm c_k)
= \chi(1)^{2 - 2g - k}\sum_{(c_1, \dotsc, c_k) \in C_1 \times \dotsb \times C_k} \chi(c_1)\dotsm\chi(c_k),
$$
or rather that
$$
\chi(1)^{k - 1}\sum_{(c_1, \dotsc, c_k) \in C_1 \times \dotsb \times C_k} \chi(c_1\dotsm c_k)
= \sum_{(c_1, \dotsc, c_k) \in C_1 \times \dotsb \times C_k} \chi(c_1)\dotsm\chi(c_k).
$$

We prove this modified result by induction.  It's obvious for $k = 1$.  (Most inductions that I know that start at $k = 1$ have an interesting degenerate case at $k = 0$, but I don't know what  the proper degenerate case is here!  Plugging in $k = 0$ naïvely doesn't work.)  In general, we have
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{c_1 \in C_1} 
\chi(c_1)\Bigl(
\sum_{(c_2, \dotsc, c_{k + 1}) \in C_2 \times \dotsb \times C_{k + 1}} \chi(c_2\dotsm c_{k + 1})
\Bigr)
\\
={} & \sum_{c_1 \in C_1}
\chi(c_1)\Bigl(
\chi(1)^{k - 1}\sum_{(c_2, \dotsc, c_{k + 1}) \in C_2 \times \dotsb \times C_{k + 1}} \chi(c_2\dotsm c_{k + 1})\Bigr) \\
={} & \chi(1)^k\sum_{(c_1, \dotsc, c_{k + 1}) \in C_1 \times \dotsb C_{k + 1}} \chi(c_1 c_2\dotsm c_{k + 1}),
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the lovely answer!  That is very nice and I was unaware of the identity that Paul Sally liked so much :-)

Comment: This works equally well, with sums over conjugacy classes replaced by normalised integrals, for compact groups.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to view things: it uses the fact that for each complex irreducible character $\chi$ of $G$, there is an algebra homomorphism $\omega_{\chi} : Z(\mathbb{C}G) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\omega_{\chi}(X) = \frac{\chi(X)}{\chi(1)} .$ This is the underlying root (from a modern viewpoint) of the formula of Frobenius quoted in the question, and the formula beloved of Paul Sally quoted in L. Spice's answer.

For $S$ a subset of $G$ invariant under conjugation, let $S^{+} = \sum_{s \in S} s$ in $\mathbb{C}G.$

Hence for each $\lambda$ we find that $$\frac{\chi_{\lambda}(C_{1}^{+}C_{2}^{+} \ldots C_{k}^{+})}{\chi_{\lambda}(1)} = \prod_{i=1}^{k} |C_{i}|\frac{\chi_{\lambda} (c_{i})}{\chi_{\lambda}(1)}.$$

Expressing the element $C_{1}^{+} \ldots C_{k}^{+}$ as a sum of products of group elements explains the formula of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer - that is a very enlightening perspective :-).  Is there a name for the map $\omega_lambda$?

Comment: It's sort of the infinitesimal character, isn't it?

Comment: As a finite group theorist, I only know it as the "central character associated to $\chi$. Its existence comes via Schur's Lemma ( which tells us that all central elements of $\mathbb{C}G$ are represented by scalar matrices), and consideration of what $\omega_{\chi}$ does to the central idempotents associated to each irreducible character. Clearly it takes value $1$ at $e_{\chi}$ and value $0$ at $e_{\mu}$ for every irreducible character $\mu$ different from $\chi$..