# A "shifted" orthogonality relation for characters of irreducible representations of finite groups?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

For $G$ any finite group and $V$ any irreducible complex representation of $G$ with character $\chi_V$, is it always true that

$$ \frac{1}{\left| G \right|} \displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} \chi_V(g)\chi_V(g^{-1}h) = \frac{\chi_V(h)}{\dim(V)}?$$

I see already that if $V$ is one-dimensional, then $\chi_V$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb C^*$ and the statement is immediate.  Also, if $h=e$, then this is just part of the orthogonality relations for characters of irreducible representations.

Also, this identity seems to be equivalent to saying that the element
$e_V=\frac{\dim(V)}{\left|G\right|}\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} \overline{\chi_V(g)}g$ in the group algebra of $G$ is an idempotent, so if the only proof leads from this fact (if it is a fact), so be it, but I was hoping for something more direct, perhaps along the lines of proofs of the orthogonality relations themselves.

Comment: Your $e_V$ is slightly off. If you multiply by dim V and replace one of the two g's by $g^{-1}$ you get a central primitive idempotent for the representation V

Comment: See [Proofs of a character identity?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388863/proofs-of-a-character-identity).

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I have added the $dim(V)$.  But if $e_V$ is an idempotent, isn't $\overline{e_V}$ too?  So is a $g \rightarrow g^{-1}$ switch needed there?  I may have missed something since most examples I looked at were real characters.

Comment: You are correct that, as defined, $e_V$ is an idempotent. But still it would avoid some confusion to switch $\chi_V(g)$ to $\chi_V(g^{-1}) = \overline{\chi_V(g)}$ as Benjamin Steinberg suggests. With your original definition $e_V$ is the idempotent projecting onto the dual representation $V^\star$. The quickest proof I know of this generalized orthogonality is the one you propose, i.e. comparing coefficients in $e_V^2 = e_V$. And more generally one can compare coefficients in $e_V e_W = [V \cong W] e_V$.

Comment: @MarkWildon - yes, that makes sense.  I changed it as you and Benjamin suggested.

Comment: @L.Spice: Can you elaborate?  Though the linked identities look related, I can't quite make the connection.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1060121), my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/388865) shows how to deduce the desired identity from yours, but I do not see how to establish the converse.

Comment: So [A character identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314913/a-character-identity) is a better link.

Comment: @L.Spice - indeed, Denis' question there is the same as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear transformation $\rho(e_V)$ to which $e_V$ maps in the representation $\rho$ on $V$.  The element $e_V$ is in the center of the group algebra.  So its image commutes with $\rho(g)$ for all $g\in G.$  But since $V$ is irreducible, by Schur's lemma, $\rho(e_V)=\lambda \textit{Id}$ for some constant $\lambda.$  And we know that the trace of $\rho(e_V)$ is $\dim(V)$ by the orthogonality relation $\left<\chi,\chi\right>=1.$  The only way this can happen is if $\rho(e_V)=\mathrm{Id}$.  To finish, look at the trace of $\rho(e_Vh).$

[Benjamin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413432/a-shifted-orthogonality-relation-for-characters-of-irreducible-representations/413516#comment1059919_413432)'s and [Mark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413432/a-shifted-orthogonality-relation-for-characters-of-irreducible-representations/413516#comment1060059_413432)'s remarks actually made this answer pop out at me once I was able to stare at $e_V$ written properly.

Comment: It seems to me that this *is* [@MarkWildon's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1060059).  But, of course, there is no harm in spelling out the details with proper credit, as you have done.  Don't forget to mark this as accepted if it answers your question (or to close your question if you [agree](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1060176) that it is a duplicate of [A character identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314913/a-character-identity)).